# How to create a part in eagle for a TO220-7 with bent leads

Tags: eaglecad

I can't seem to find such a reference within the library. How could I make  my own footprint? I'm using the latest version of eagle 6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create your own footprint in eagle, easiest option is to take an existing TO220 package and adjust it. This avoids the hassle of silkscreen and other things. The modification you need is very simple, to move the location of the pads so that they will coincide with the leads.

Take the TO220-7 specification (from datasheet or whatever) and look at what is the pitch between the leads. Then go to eagle, right click on each pad and do properties. Shift them in the proper axis the right amount for them to have the proper spacing. For example, if the central pin is located at (0,0) and each lead needs to be 1mm, then place center pad at (0,0), left lead at (-1,0) and right lead at (1,0). Doing it mathematically is easier, faster and more accurate than doing it visually.

Modify silkscreen as needed and don't forget to modify the description.

There a nice [tutorial](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/110) in sparkfun about the actual details.